# Finding the sum of a nested list without using itertools

Tags: python, list

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,1],[2,2,6],[3]]
```

the sum of a would print 24

I know for a single list such as `[1,2,3]` i can just do `sum(a)` but I'm struggling with a nested list.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not create a new temporary list:

```
sum(sum(b) for b in a)
```

Comment: +1.  This just as clear as `sum(itertools.chain(*a))`.  However, I'm not sure why someone would simply rule out `itertools`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but i'm very new could you possibly explain what b is standing for? I just cannot wrap my head around it, maybe i need some sleep.

Comment: @jack:  `b` is one of your sublists.  To see how this works use a for-loop: `for b in a:print b`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sum(sum(a, []))
```

The inner sum combines all the individual lists into one list. The outer sum then finds the actual sum.

For lists that are nested more than one deep, you can use this:

```
def recursiveSum(data):
    try:
        total = 0
        for item in data:
            total += recursiveSum(item)
        return total
    except TypeError: #data isn't iterable, it's probably a number
        return data

print recursiveSum([[[[1,2,3],[4,1]],[2,2,6]],3])
```

output:

```
24
```

Comment: This has the potential to horribly inefficient.  Each time a list is added a new and ever larger list is created.